# Request simulation plugin for grails

Tags: performance, grails

I have been searching for a grails plugin that ca be used to simulate requests. I have a jersey service that calls some helper methods and I'm trying to check if any of these methods are bottleneck method, I found this **[JavaMelody Grails Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody)**, . But, this tool does not create request simulation, it rather measure the actual traffic.

Anybody knows a free profiler that can drill down to the helper methods level?

Comment: You might be better off using a tool such as JMeter to do the kind of testing with I *think* you want to do.

Comment: if i'm testing a jersey service could jmeter drill down to the helper methods level or it will just tell me how long the whole service took?

Comment: It'll only tell you how long the whole request took - maybe I'm misunderstanding your requirements.

Comment: No, I was not clear enough, thanks anyways

Comment: I use YourKit for profiling java apps.  Could you just attach that to your server process, then just send a request from browser as usual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of load simulator, like Jmeter, as well as a profiling tool are your best bet to get the sorts of information I think you are after. Though I try not to promote proprietary solutions, New Relic will, I think, give you the sorts of real-time profiling you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jmeter can generate request load, you can also use [badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) this allows you to record and then play in threads or optionally you can export for Jmeter file so can be used for more complex request generation.